# Choosing a selection for a quiz

Tags: python-3.x

This is a basic quiz program which allows the user to answer questions on topics and choose a difficulty for that topic.

As you can see, the coding itself is incredibly long therefore can cost a lot of time because the code essentially repeats itself due to the if and elif statements. Is there a method of condensing this code?

```
choices = input ("Choose 'c' for capital city's or 's' for songs:")
mode = input ("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard: ")

if choices == "c" and mode == "e":
    q = input ("What is the capital of China?")
    qTwo = input ("What is the capital city of Denmark?")

elif choices == "c" and mode == "m":
    qThree = input("Is there a capital city of antartica?")
    qFour = input("What is the current capital of India?")

elif choices == "c" and mode == "h":
    qFive = int(input("How many capitals are their in the world?")
    qSix = input("What was the old capital of China called?")
```

Comment: What part of your code snippet do you think is _incredibly long_?

Comment: Consider using a data structure such as an array to contain the questions and answers instead of integrating the program logic with the data.

Comment: What I consider long is the if and elif statements due to the fact I must repeat these statements again for creating the questions for songs. @mattias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put the questions and answers into lists and then assign the chosen list to a variable over which you loop with a `for` loop to get the current question and answer.

```
import random

# First put the questions into separate lists.
# The lists contain tuples of the question and the answer.
capital_questions_easy = [
    ("What is the capital of China?", "Beijing"),
    ("What is the capital city of Denmark?", "Copenhagen"),
    ]

capital_questions_medium = [
    ("Is there a capital city of Antartica?", "No"),
    ("What is the current capital of India?", "New Delhi"),
    ]

capital_questions_hard = [
    ("How many capitals are their in the world?", "206"),
    ("What was the old capital of China called?", "No distinct answer"),
    ]

# A while loop to handle incorrect user input.
while True:
    mode = input("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard: ")
    if mode in ("e", "m", "h"):
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")

# Assign the chosen list to another variable. You could
# use a dictionary here as well.
if mode == "e":
    questions = capital_questions_easy
elif mode == "m":
    questions = capital_questions_medium
elif mode == "h":
    questions = capital_questions_hard

# Randomize the questions. Note that `questions` is just a reference
# to the original list, so it is shuffled as well. Create a copy
# if you want to avoid this.
random.shuffle(questions)

score = 0

# Now ask the questions in a for loop. I unpack the
# (question, answer) tuples directly in the head of the
# loop into the variables `question` and `answer`.
for question, answer in questions:
    user_input = input(question + ' ')
    if user_input == answer:
        score += 1
        print('Correct. Score:', score)
    else:
        print('Incorrect. The correct answer is:', answer)
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, How would I incorporate a while loop when choosing a difficulty? And is this validation?

Comment: Yes, data validation. I've just added the while loop to the example. Without it the user could just enter what he wants and the program would crash.